Geometric argument for why $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}_2) = c$ is a circle
Let $\mathbf{p}_1, \mathbf{p}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2, c \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then the equation $(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}_1)\cdot (\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{p}_2) = c$ defines a circle with centre $\frac{\mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{p}_2}{2}$.
We can see this algebraically by expanding the equation to $\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{x} - (\mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{p}_2)\cdot\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{p}_1\cdot\mathbf{p}_2 = c$ and completing the square, giving $\left\lvert\left\lvert\mathbf{x}-\left(\frac{\mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{p}_2}{2}\right)\right\rvert\right\rvert^2=R^2$, where $R^2=\left\lvert\left\lvert\frac{\mathbf{p}_1 - \mathbf{p}_2}{2}\right\rvert\right\rvert^2+c$
My question is whether there's a way to use the geometric meaning of the dot product to interpret the original equation in a way that makes it clear why it gives a circle (or sphere in higher dimensions).
In the case where $c=0$, I can understand geometrically what's going on using Thales' Theorem and its converse, but I don't know how to think about this geometric property of "two vectors having constant dot product" for other values of $c$.

Edit: I accidentally asked a slightly different question to the one I intended to ask -- I'm looking for "enlightening" explanations for why this equation would correspond to a circle, since I didn't feel especially enlightened by crunching out the algebra. I assumed such an explanation would likely be geometric, but any explanation which provides insight is definitely welcomed, even if it happens to not involve much geometry.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem seems related, but I can't quite connect the two.

I suspect the answer is the inscribed angle theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle

I was thinking it could be the inscribed angle theorem, since that's a natural generalisation of Thales' theorem, but the two fixed points don't necessarily live on the circle (they live on its diameter).
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pnqu2u9yxq
I've made a quick visualisation of the equation in desmos so make it easier to see how changes to c affect the graph.

Actually if I squint a little this almost looks like an ellipse plus two foci, so the argument might involve starting with these two points as the foci of some ellipse whose major axis is the same as the radius of the circle we want. I'll need to look into how ellipses are represented using vectors to see if anything can be done with this.

Perhaps it has to do with the length of the median of a triangle -- after all, the radius of the circle is the length of the median of the triangle formed by the two vectors?

I think this interpretation matches the equation very nicely after the square has been completed, since the vector for the median is just x minus the average of the two points, but I still don't quite see how to relate this back to the original equation.

What do you think the "geometric meaning" of the dot product is? Apparently the accepted answer (since it's accepted) must relate to this meaning somehow, but I can't see how. Perhaps we have different ideas about "geometric meaning."

Looking back I think I asked the wrong question, since what I was actually looking for was an "enlightening" explanation for why this property would define a circle, since I didn't feel particularly enlightened by the algebra crunch, and the equation seemed to not have many moving pieces. I fully realise that this is even vaguer than my original question. I found the decomposition of of vectors into m+-d to be somewhat enlightening, which is why I accepted, but I think I agree with you that it doesn't answer the question I actually asked, and I was a little trigger-happy in accepting it.

To actually answer your question though, I guess "geometric meaning" would probably involve something to do with its relation to angles and/or projection+scaling, but I definitely welcome any answer that provides insight even if it doesn't strictly adhere to these parameters.

Ah, that explains everything. It might be worth appending some of this to the question itself.

Lemma.
Let $P_1$, $P_2$ and $X$ be points (possibly equal) in the plane. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $P_1$ and $P_2$. Then the dot product of $\vec{P_1X}$ and $\vec{P_2X}$ is just
$$\vec{P_1X}\cdot \vec{P_2X}\equiv MX^2-\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2$$
Proof.
\begin{align*}
MX^2&=\vec{MX}\cdot \vec{MX}\\
&=(\vec{MP_2}+\vec{P_2X})\cdot (\vec{MP_1}+\vec{P_1X})\\
&=(\frac{1}{2}\vec{P_1P_2}+\vec{P_2X})\cdot (-\frac{1}{2}\vec{P_1P_2}+\vec{P_1X})\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2-\frac{1}{2}\vec{P_2X}\cdot \vec{P_1P_2}+\frac{1}{2}\vec{P_1P_2}\cdot\vec{P_1X}+\vec{P_1X}\cdot\vec{P_2X}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{P_2X}-\vec{P_1X})\cdot\vec{P_1P_2}+\vec{P_1X}\cdot\vec{P_2X}\\
&=-\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2+\frac{1}{2}P_1P_2^2+\vec{P_1X}\cdot\vec{P_2X}\\
&=\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2+\vec{P_1X}\cdot\vec{P_2X}\\
\end{align*}
$$\square$$
Now given this, let $X$ be a point on a circle of radius $R$ centred at $M$. Then $MX^2=R^2$ and hence $\vec{P_1X}\cdot \vec{P_2X}=R^2-\frac{1}{4}P_1P_2^2$ is constant.

Okay so if I understand correctly you're essentially using a vector analog of the fact that a product xy can be expressed as a difference of two squares, (m+d)(m-d), where m=(x+y)/2 is the midpoint of the two numbers, and d = |x-y|/2 is half of the distance between the two numbers.

With this specific choice of vectors, d turns out to be the distance between the two fixed points, and m turns out to be the length of the vector pointing from the midpoint of the two points towards the variable point (the "radius"). Since we've enforced that the product is fixed, and the distance between the fixed points also has to be fixed, this forces the "radius" to be fixed, and so we get a circle. Neat!

I found Joshua Tilley's proof too algebraic to give much intuition, so here are a few ways of thinking about this which may give a better way to visualise why the equation defines a circle.
1. Move the fixed points
Suppose we move the two fixed points to $\mathbf{p}_1' = \mathbf{p}_1 + \mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{p}_2' = \mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{d}$ respectively, for some adjustment $\mathbf{d}$. Then
$$(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_1') \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_2') = \underbrace{(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_2})}_{(*)} + (\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot \mathbf{d} - |\mathbf{d}|^2$$
So if $(*)$ stays constant while $\mathbf{x}$ varies, so does the left-hand side. So apply this with $\mathbf{d} = \frac{\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{p}_1}{2}$, such that $\mathbf{p}_1' = \mathbf{p}_2' = \mathbf{m}$, the midpoint. The left-hand side above becomes
$$(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}) = |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}|^2$$
which when held constant of course defines a circle centred at $\mathbf{m}$. We can also derive from above that the constant value becomes $c + |\mathbf{d}|^2$, so the radius is the square root of that.
2. Differentiation
Take a point $\mathbf{x}' = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{h}$ where $\mathbf{h}$ is some small offset. We want to investigate which direction $\mathbf{h}$ should take for the equation to still be satisfied (to the first order). We have
$$(\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_2) = (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_2}) - \underbrace{2 \mathbf{h} \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m})}_{(\dagger)} + O(h^2)$$
To eliminate the first-order term $(\dagger)$, we should set $\mathbf{h}$ to be perpendicular to $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}$. This implies that every tangent of the shape is perpendicular to the "radius" from the midpoint $\mathbf{m}$, and hence that the shape is a circle.
3. Three dimensions
Consider the same equation in three dimensions rather than two, where the $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$ are assumed to lie in the plane $z = 0$ but $\mathbf{x}$ might not. Then we want to understand why the equation defines a sphere.
Consider $\mathbf{x}$ constrained to the plane $z = \sqrt{c}$, which we can write as $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{x}' + \sqrt{c}\,\mathbf{e}_z$ so that $\mathbf{x}'$ is constrained to the plane $z = 0$. Then
$$(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_2) = (\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_2) + c$$
because the only contribution of the $z$ components is from $\mathbf{x}$. Then, since the left-hand side is presumed to be constant with the value $c$, then the term $(\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x}' - \mathbf{p}_2)$ is constant with the value $0$. Therefore, as noted in the question, the converse of Thales' theorem implies that the intersection of the shape with the plane $z = \sqrt{c}$ is a circle which passes over the two points, and its centre lies above their midpoint.
We can then consider rotations in 3D space about the axis which passes through $\mathbf{p}_1$ and $\mathbf{p}_2$. Such rotations preserve the dot product $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_1) \cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_2)$, so if any point $\mathbf{x}$ is on the shape, then the shape includes the whole circle of points in a plane perpendicular to the rotation axis. These rotations of our circle from the plane $z = \sqrt{c}$ produce a sphere centred at $\mathbf{m}$ with two caps removed. By Pythagoras' theorem, the radius of the sphere is $\sqrt{\left|\frac{\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{p_1}}{2}\right|^2 + c}$.
For the sake of intuition, I think it's enough to have shown that the shape includes most of the sphere. (We could argue that the rest of the sphere is included based on the fact that the equation is a polynomial of degree 2 so it must define a quadric surface, for example.) It's also worth noting that this argument depends on $c > 0$, whereas $c$ might be negative in the original equation. Nonetheless, I thought it was worth presenting this idea too, because (in my opinion) rotating a circle in three dimensions to make a sphere is a more compelling visual.

Sorry for the paragraph beginning "The fact that this displacement", I'm not quite sure I fully follow the logic. I get that rotating vectors doesn't change their dot product, and scaling them scales the dot product, but don't these properties only imply that the image of the shape traced out by the equation after this transformation is a rotated/scaled version of the original image? I don't quite see why this implies that the shape has rotational symmetry about m, which seems necessary to conclude that the image before and after the rotation are identical (up to some scale factor)

@wolfe This wasn't meant to be an argument from rotational symmetry, but rather about the form of the equation. However, I can't remember exactly what I had in mind when I wrote it, and it does look incorrect for the reason you stated. I will edit.

Consider the law of cosines on the triangle $\triangle xp_1p_2$:
$$
|p_1p_2|^2 = |xp_1|^2 + |xp_2|^2 - 2|xp_1||xp_2|\cos\angle x
$$
Note that the last term here is exactly twice the given dot product, which is assumed to be constant for all valid points $x$. And the left-hand side of this equality is clearly constant. So that means that $|xp_1|^2 + |xp_2|^2$ is assumed to remain constant as $x$ vary.
Let $o$ be the center of the segment $p_1p_2$. Draw the normal from $x$ down to the line $p_1p_2$ and let $y$ be the intersection point between the normal and the line. See below picture for an illustration.

$xp_1$ and $xp_2$ are now the hypotenuses of two right triangles in this figure. Since $|xp_1|^2 + |xp_2|^2$ is constant, the Pythagorean theorem tells us that
$$
\left(|xy|^2 + |yp_1|^2\right) + \left(|xy|^2 + |yp_2|^2\right)
$$
is constant. Insert $|yp_1| = |yo| + |op_1|$ and $|yp_2| = |yo| - |op_2|$ in the above (this requires some care in the general case, because we don't know whether $y$ is outside $p_2$, outside $p_1$, or between $p_1$ and $p_2$), and we get that
$$
|xy|^2 + |yo|^2 + 2|yo||op_1| + |op_1|^2 + |xy|^2 + |yo|^2 -2|yo||op_2| + |op_2|^2
$$
is constant. Since $|op_1|^2$ and $|op_2|^2$ are constant, we may disregard these. Also note that $2|yo||op_1| = 2|yo||op_2|$, so those two terms cancel. We are left with the constant expression
$$
2|xy|^2 + 2|yo|^2 
$$
which by the Pythagorean theorem tells us that $2|ox|^2$ is constant, and therefore $x$ traces out a circle as it varies.

Without looking too closely at it, I suspect that this is essentially very close to Joshua Tilly's proof. My phrasing is just a tiny bit more classically geometric.

I figured out an explanation which uses the intersecting chords theorem.



Let $P_1$, $P_2$ respectively be the endpoints of the position vectors $\mathbf{p_1}$ and $\mathbf{p_2}$
Let $M$ be the midpoint of $P_1$ and $P_2$.
Fix a circle $\mathcal{C}$ centred at $M$, and let $X$ be any point on this circle. Let $\mathbf{x}$ be the position vector of $X$.
Let $X'$ be the point on $\mathcal{C}$ such that $XX'$ is a diameter. Extend $X'P_1$ until it intersects $\mathcal{C}$ and let this intersection point be $Y$.
Let $\angle P_1X'P_2$ be $\theta$.
Let $x_1 = |P_1X|$ (which is also equal to $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_1}|$)
Let $x_2 = |P_2X|$ (which is also equal to $|\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_2}|$)

Since $X'X$ is a diameter, $\angle X'YX$ is a right angle (Thales' Theorem).
By congruent triangles, we have that $|X'P_1|=x_2$ and $P_1X \parallel X'P_2$, so $\angle YP_1X = \theta$.
Hence $|P_1Y|=x_1\cos(\theta)$
By considering $\angle P_1X'P_2$ we have that $(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_1})\cdot (\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_2}) = |\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_1}||\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p_2}|\cos(\theta)=x_1x_2\cos(\theta)$
But we also have that this quantity is equal to  $|X'P_1||P_1Y|$, which is constant as we vary $X$ around this circle via the intersecting chords theorem.
Furthermore, circles with different radii yield different values for this product, which is probably most easily seen by considering the chord perpendicular to $P_1M$ through $P_1$.

Here's a constructive argument
Notice that for any two vectors $\mathbf{r}, \mathbf{v}$,  $(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{v})\cdot (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{r}^2- \mathbf{v}^2$ and $\dfrac{(\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{v})+(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{v})}{2} = \mathbf{r}$
Now let $\mathbf{r}$ be the vector from point $\mathbf{x}$ to a fixed point $\mathbf{m}$. Let point $\mathbf{p_1}$ and point $\mathbf{p_2}$ be $\mathbf{m}+\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{m}-\mathbf{v}$ respectively. We have

$\mathbf{m}$ is the mid point of segment $\mathbf{p_1}\mathbf{p_2}$
$\mathbf{p}_1 = \mathbf{x} + (\mathbf{r}+\mathbf{v})$ and $\mathbf{p}_2 = \mathbf{x} + (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{v})$

Thus $(\mathbf{p}_1 -x)(\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{r}^2 - \mathbf{v}^2$
If $\mathbf{v}$ is fixed then $\mathbf{p_1}$ and $\mathbf{p_2}$ are fixed. Furthermore, if $(\mathbf{p}_1 -x)(\mathbf{p}_2 - \mathbf{x})$ is also a constant then $\mathbf{r}^2$ is also a constant
Which means $\mathbf{x}$ is on a circle with center $\mathbf{m}$, which is the midpoint of $\mathbf{p_1}\mathbf{p_2}$

The constant $c$ can be taken either positive or negative, making it possible to geometrically interpret the relation as the power of circles, with origin outside or inside.. shown in the somewhat roughly drawn hand sketch:

Actually Mohr Circles represent tensors in mechanics of materials  e.g., stress, strain, curvature and moment of inertia.
